# Is there a way to send a zip file from server via api using flask-python?

Tags: python, rest, flask, ubuntu-18.04, flask-restful

I need to develop an api in which zip file is stored in server and gets synced at client side when requested by it. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a file flask provides the `send_file()` function.

```
return send_file('<FILE_PATH>', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='<FILE_ATTACHMENT_NAME>')
```

Here the [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_file) to the documentation

Comment: can we send it in via Response such that when client requests for the file download, in response these files are downloaded at local device?

Comment: If you want to use flask's Response class you can load the file into an object of type **BytesIO** and then return it `return Response(bytes_io_object, mimetype="<correct_mime_type>")`

Comment: As for where the files are saved, obviously it must be the client-side application that requests the file that must manage the saving to local device

Comment: great! thats really helpful.